# Number of components in sklearn PCA

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-algebra, pca, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I have a problem to understand the maximum number of components in sklearn's PCA method. The documentation says that if no number is specified it will choose:

```
n_components == min(n_samples, n_features)
```

Now lets consider an example:

I have a matrix with 100 data values and 3000 features resulting in a matrix of size 100 x 3000. The corresponding covariance matrix should have the size 3000 x 3000, according to this there should exist 3000 possible eigenvalues.

Now the question: Why is the maximum of components always the smaller number of samples and features, in this case 100, even if I specify 3000 as parameter?

Comment: There's a few ways to interpret PCA, each of which explain the reason a little differently. The algorithm computes the skinny ("economy-mode") singular value decomposition of A.A^T, which computes only as many singular values/vectors as the minimal dimension. Another way to see this—PCA gives you a set of orthogonal linear combination of features that best describe the data. If you have only 100 samples, at most you can describe only 100 orthogonal vectors without fitting to numerical noise. Does that help?

Comment: @AhmedFasih This helps a lot, thank you.

Comment: If it qualifies as an answer, it should be made into one.